# Split raw html String to lines again in Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

So I extracted the raw html code from a website, but it was all put in one string, I want to split it into lines just like the "view page source" on google chrome.

This is my code.

String url = "https://stratechery.com/2016/how-google-cloud-platform-is-challenging-aws/";
        //crawl(url," more Complete Footwear.txt",9000);

```
    System.out.println(br2nl(url));
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .data("query", "Java")
            .userAgent("Mozilla")
            .cookie("auth", "token")
            .timeout(3000)
            .post();
    String rawhtml =doc.toString();
     String lines[] = rawhtml.split("\""+" ");
```

I tried to split the "rawhtml" string based on quotes and spaces but they are all over every line so it made splits everywhere.

Comment: i don't see where you are trying to split the string, please add relevant code

Comment: Okay, added it to the code now. I basically tried to split at every double quote followed by a space but it didn't work.

Comment: you might want to parse the html tags and then split the entire string to resolve this. double quotes doesn't look like a good way of solving this

Comment: I don't understand the problem - System.out.println(doc.toString()); prints the source code with line breaks, exactly as in "view page source"

Comment: Exactly but I want to extract line by line to parse it. @Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be missing the point of Jsoup.

**You don't have to do the parsing yourself line by line, Jsoup has methods to do that. The HTML is already parsed in the JSOUP Document you created. You can now access its elements one by one, or in a grouped fashion.** The possibilities are endless, take a look at the official docs: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/

To answer your question nonetheless, to split the whole HTML String by newlines, you could do this:

```
public class JsoupTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String url = "https://stratechery.com/2016/how-google-cloud-platform-is-challenging-aws/";

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
        .userAgent("Mozilla")
        .get();

    for (String s : doc.toString().split("\\n")) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
  }
}
```